# JSF - Redirect and pass an attribute

Tags: security, jsf, parameter-passing, http-redirect

I have two facelets pages (login.xhtml and user-registration.xhtml). In the login page I have two forms, one for the login and another for the user registration (where I only ask for the email and password twice).

I would like to pass the email and password as attributes from the user registration form to the user-registration.xhtml page (where I ask for the rest of the user registration fields). I don't want to pass them as parameters in the GET url for security reasons.

Can I pass them as attributes while doing a redirect to the user-registration.xhtml page?

Comment: you can use the `<f:param name="dataInformations" value="data"></f:param>` and `add outcome="redricted"` did you try this ?!?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<p:button outcome="page2" >
    <f:param name="nameofData" value="theInformation"></f:param>
</p:button>
```

I suppose that this composant is in the `page1.xhtml` and the `page1` and `page2` are in the same folder (in case note you need to change your `outcome`) , and for your param you will send `theInformation` with a name in our case it is `nameofData` and you will get the informations with `nameofData`.

Hope that helped you

Comment: But I want to pass them as attributes, not as parameters

Comment: that's something different you need to call your managedBean and change his type to save your data (for example @ViewScoped is used with users every user had his own managedBean and every time he stopped working with it it will be destroyed)